# Passing ArrayList reference to another class

Tags: java, reference, arraylist

I understood that Objects are passed as references in Java.
So, Is it **correct** to do like this? ArrayList is created in parent procedure, then passed to procedure in another class for creating new set of elements in it.

```
class DO_Thing {
 private static ArrayList<ElementClass> fr = new ArrayList<>();

 public static void do_main() {
    fr= Functions.add_elements(fr);
 }
}

public class Functions {
     public static ArrayList<ElementClass> add_elements(ArrayList<ElementClass > frk) {
        ElementClass ier;
        ResultSet zuzis;
        frk.clear();
        zuzis = dbini.db_getallrow("frakcijas");
        try {
            while (zuzis.next()) {
                ier = new Frakcijas();
                ier.frid = zuzis.getInt("frakcijas_id");
                ier.frnos = zuzis.getString("nosaukums");
                frk.add(ier);
            }
        } catch (SQLException a) {
            System.out.println(a);
        }
        return frk;
    }
}
```

Comment: all your identifiers are in the wrong language.

Comment: "I understood that Objects are passed as references in Java" - no, the value of the reference is passed, not the reference itself.

Comment: No, java does pass by value. This is a good answer on the Java references and parameters being passed into methods. http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html. What you are doing is fine (taking a parameter and returning the result).

Comment: yes, value of reference is passed, I understood now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Objects are not passed as references, but passed is the value of the reference.
2. Your code will work, but there is no need to pass the empty `ArrayList`, when invoking the  `ielikt_frakcijas()` method, since you only `clear` it.

What you can do :

```
public static ArrayList<Frakcijas> ielikt_frakcijas() {
   Frakcijas ier;
   ResultSet zuzis;
   ArrayList<Frakcijas> result = new ArrayList<Frakcijas>();
   zuzis = dbini.db_getallrow("frakcijas");
   try {
       while (zuzis.next()) {
           ier = new Frakcijas();
           ier.frid = zuzis.getInt("frakcijas_id");
           ier.frnos = zuzis.getString("nosaukums");
           result.add(ier);
       }
   } catch (SQLException a) {
       System.out.println(a);
   }
   return result;
}
```

and invoke it like:

```
frakcijas = Funkcijas.ielikt_frakcijas();
```

Comment: Thanks, that did not come into my head before.

Answer (score 2):

Functionally, yes. This is a variation on the [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) object construction pattern.